# IPrincipal from WCF request

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, security, wcf-security

Can i get the requester windows IPrincipal when he comsume WCF service?

Comment: Perhaps. Really need a bit more info as to how you are accessing the service.

Comment: Well, i'm using WCF using Windows Authentication, i configured specific user to the application pool so it will have the DB credentials. which more details necessaries?
thanx

Comment: What binding / protocols are you using? Are the client and the server in the same network segment / Active Directory domain?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using this code, you can examine the current security context inside your WCF service.

If the user is authenticated, and the WindowsPrincipal is not null, then you're using a Windows security model - you can access all the relevant info:

```
ServiceSecurityContext current = ServiceSecurityContext.Current;

if (!current.IsAnonymous && current.WindowsIdentity != null)
{
    string userName = current.WindowsIdentity.Name;
}
```

Comment: thanx a lot!
i disable to mark this as answer somehow.
Thank you anyway.
Tamir